# Retrieve comments for posts (model relations) in AngularJS against a restful Api using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

EDIT: I've decided to go with Restangular since it seems that the Lodash library plays pretty well with AngularJS. I still have one more question. Restangular's getList() function expects the response to be an array however my server responses include two parameters, only one of which is an array. Something like this:

```
{"error": "false", "topics": [{"id":"1", "title":"someTitle"},{"id":"2", "title":"someTitle2"}]}
```

I assume I would set this in the RestangularProvider.setResourceInterceptor but I'm not quite sure how. Any options? I was able to read the response from a .json file which I made an array so at least I know I'm reading it right. :)

UPDATE: I tried this but i get: TypeError: Cannot set property 'metadata' of undefined

```
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  var newResponse;
  // This is a get for a list
  if (operation === "getList") {
    // First the newResponse will be response.topics which is actually an array
    newResponse = response.topics;
    // Then we add to this array a special property containing the metadata for paging for example
    newResponse.metadata = response.data.meta;
  } else {
    // If it's an element, then we just return the "regular" response as there's no object wrapping it
   newResponse = response;
  }
  return newResponse;
});
```

<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

I'm pretty new to angularJS and still unsure about several things regarding CRUD operations. I've heard a lot of praise for ngResource but also suggestions that $http was better for more complex model relations. I have a specific problem here and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. For this example I opted for using ngResource, though I'm not too sure how much I like its data handling. I have two resources on my Api, topics and comments. The Api endpoints are as follows:

```
http://api.example.com/v1/topics //To get all topics
http://api.example.com/v1/topics/:id //To get a single topic
http://api.example.com/v1/topics/:id/comments //To get all comments for a single topic
```

I've written the following code to get the topics:

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $resource, $location, $http, localStorageService, requestNotification) {

  var Topic = $resource('http://api.discussorama.com/v1/topics/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    query: {
        isArray: false,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'X-Api-Secret': 'xxx', 'Authorization': 'xxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }
  });

  var topics = Topic.query();
  topics.$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.topics = data.topics;
  });

});
```

And then used it in my view like this (no problems yet):

```
<div ng-repeat="t in topics | orderBy:'created_at':true" class="topic">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 topic_body">
      <h3 class="topic_title">{{ t.topic_title }}</h3>
      <h5 class="topic_subtitle">Posted by {{ t.name }}</h5>
      <hr>
      <img ng-src="{{ t.image_url }}" class="img-responsive"/>
      <p class="topic_content">{{ t.topic_content }}</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img ng-src="{{ t.profile_pic }}" width="60px"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do now is query the comments Api endpoint within the ng-repeat of the topics to display the comments for that particular topic. Is there a way to pass t.id from the ng-repeat to replace the :id in [http://api.example.com/topics/:id/comments](http://api.example.com/topics/%3aid/comments) and how would I go about this. Also would I be better off using $http or is ngResource a good module for this job. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Restangular (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) helps with that. It can construct an url for you from parameters. It might take a couple hours of understanding how it all works but I think it would help you out

Comment: I've looked into it. Seems quite robust, I might end up going in that direction but I'm still interested to see if anyone has experience doing this with $http or ngResource. Still, thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: Restangular also has additional dependencies which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot  of looking around I've learned the answer to at least my original question. And angularjs truly does handle it beautifully. Basically by adding an ng-controller to an item with ng-repeat you can now play with the items on an item by item basis. Full example code with my solution is below if anyone is interested.

```
//index.html

<!doctype html/>
<html ng-app="restApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <head>
    <title>Get Comments from Topic</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-repeat="topic in topics" ng-controller="topicController">
      <h1>{{ topic.topic_title }}</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
        <h3>{{ comment.comment }}</h3>
        <p>{{ comment.author_name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/restangular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My controllers:

```
// app.js

var app = angular.module("restApp", ["restangular"]);

app.config(
  function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://api.example.com/v1');
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({"Authorization": "..."});
  }
);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers
    .common['X-Requested-With'];
});

app.controller("mainController", ["Restangular","$scope", function(Restangular, $scope){
  $scope.message = "Welcome to REST";
  var topics = Restangular.all('topics');
  var allTopics = topics.getList().then(function(topics){
    $scope.topics = topics;
    console.log($scope.topics);
  });
}]);

app.controller("topicController", ["Restangular", "$scope", function(Restangular, $scope){
  var oneTopic = Restangular.one('topics', $scope.topic.id);
  oneTopic.get().then(function(topic) {
    topic.getList('comments').then(function(comments){
      $scope.comments = comments;
      console.log($scope.comments);
    });
  });
}]);
```

If anyone has had any success with extracting an array out of an object response for Restangular.getList() please let me know. For now I've added a version of my API that sends responses as arrays to work around this issue.